# How to use current locale in @Async method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, localization

I have a service which has methods sending emails asyncronously. Sender method has an `@Async` annotation. But when I try to use current locale in that method, It always the default one. So question is how to pass locale to `@Async` methods.

Comment: Just pass it into the method.

Comment: can you share your example code?

Comment: @M.Deinum Is there more general and elegant solution than to pass Locale in every method?

Comment: @pleft Sorry, there is a kind of complex logic around

Comment: Not really... It runs in a different thread, so using `LocaleContextHolder` isn't an option as that is based on a `ThreadLocal` (that is also why you are getting the default `Locale` instead of the one you expect).

Comment: @M.Deinum I used different approach. Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to implement custom `AsyncTaskExecutor` which would take a Locale as a parameter. Then it would set a locale to its context.

```
public interface LocaleAsyncTaskExecutor extends AsyncTaskExecutor {
    void execute(Runnable task, Locale locale);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution of chunhoong worked for me, but It's not so semantic.
There was a better solution for me: Set the same request context for all threads. The main and all the @Async threads should share the DispatcherServlet context (setThreadContextInheritable(true)). It worked like a charm:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoreApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication
                .run(CoreApplication.class, args)
                .getBean(DispatcherServlet.class)
                .setThreadContextInheritable(true);
    }
}
```

PS: This helped me a lot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14079

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are accessing your current locale using LocaleContextHolder.

Before execute your async method, set your current locale into LocaleContextHolder with inheritable flag set to true, eg:

```
Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(currentLocale, true);
```

The LocaleContext will be inherited by any child threads spawned by the current thread when the inheritable flag is set to true, which behaves like a thread-local.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html#setLocale-java.util.Locale-boolean-